# Spring security integration without using annotation

Tags: java, annotations, spring-security

I have to integrate spring security to my application. I didn't use annotation for mapping, Simply did all the mappings using application-Context.xml. Now I want to integrate spring security, So I followed this tutorial http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration_18.html in this they are using annotation based spring security. But I want to do the same without using annotation.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `protect-pointcut` element in your namespace configuration.

[Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-global-method)'s how.

Also if your doing it for the first time I **strongly** recommend doing [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html) tutorial first.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any annotations regarding spring security in the tutorial you specified , "spring-security.xml" is all that you want in that tutorial.you can find [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html) also.Spring provides annotations for method security only,even though you can use **protect-pointcut** for securing methods.For example

```
 <global-method-security>
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* *..service.UserManager.getUsers(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
  </global-method-security>
```

according to above pointcut,only users with the ROLE_ADMIN role will be able to invoke thes UserManager's  clss getUsers() method.